# What happens during auto vacuum / vacuum in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

The official documentaion here seemed quite cryptic to me. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM

Can someone offer an explanation of what happens under the hood during autovacuum or manually triggerred vacuum?

Comment: https://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql06.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autovacuum launcher process wakes up regularly and determines – based on the statistical data in `pg_stat_all_tables` and `pg_class` and certain parameters settings – if a table needs to be `VACUUM`ed or `ANALYZE`d. If yes, it starts an autovacuum worker process that performs the required operation.

`VACUUM` does a lot of things. The basic procedure is:

- scan the table for dead row versions
- scan all indexes and remove references to these dead row versions
- scan the table again to remove the dead row versions found in the first step
- if we are not done with the table yet, repeat the whole process

On the side lines, it also does these things:

- update table statistics in `pg_class`
- bring the “free space map” up to date, so that `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s know where to find a block with enough free space
- bring the “visibility map” up to date, so that PostgreSQL can perform efficient index-only scans
- “freeze” all live rows older than a certain age to allow the transaction ID counter to wrap around without data loss